# How do I pass button clicks to other subroutines?

Tags: vb.net, button, event-handling

I am very new in coding. I can work myself around a working program but this is my first time creating from scratch. Here is my code, yes I know it's probably messy right now.

What I am trying to do sounds simple enough logically.

theory:
This app has multiple buttons when clicked each one will bring up a question. once answered the labels will change to ask another question. so on and so fourth until I run out. This is intended to be a user simple application for step-by-step troubleshooting some test equipment.

I can't seem to figure out why I can't just say if buttonYes=true then blah blah. I don't feel that it is complicated as it seems. I have searched around the forums but I can't seem to find anything like this.

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDg2q.png)

```
Public Class Form1



Class EventHandler


    Public Event buttonYes(ByVal Status As String)

    Private Sub buttonYes_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles buttonYes.Click
        RaiseEvent buttonYes("True")

    End Sub




End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    buttonYes.Hide()
    buttonNo.Hide()
    title.Hide()
    question.Hide()
    action.Hide()

    title.Text = ""
    question.Text = ""
    action.Text = ""

End Sub



Private Sub buttonNo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonNo.Click

    Dim ans As String
    ans = "False"

End Sub

Private Sub CompButton(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles compFail.Click

    buttonYes.Show()
    buttonNo.Show()
    title.Show()
    question.Show()
    action.Show()

    title.Text = "Component / SAT"
    question.Text = "Are all cables seated properly"

End Sub

Private Sub ComponentFail(ByVal ans)
    'Dim ans As String
    ans = ""

    If ans = "False" Then
        action.Text = "Check cable connections and retest"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub buttonYes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to learn a lot about variable scopes. In essence, a variable declared internally a sub/function, is local to that sub/function and is not visible outside of that method. It doesn't matter if you declare another variable with the same name. They are not the same variable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: VB has a VBYesNo pop up dialogue  box, you assign your ans to the return of that pop up dialogue box.  I use these in VBA (derivative of VB), based on ans you then conditionally branch.

Comment: Steve, my brain hurts.

Comment: This is not how event programming works: `If buttonYes.Click = True Then`

Comment: @RussellGray, Are you doing this to learn Event handling? Or is this an application that will be used in a business setting? If the latter, a desktop application might not be the best way to implement it...

Comment: Yes to learn event handling.

Comment: First enable [Option Strict](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic-net-and-in-visual-ba) as it will allow VS to flag many of the issues in the code you posted.  Second, embrace the documentation.  You are using the [Button Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you had investigated the [Click Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netframework-4.7.2) you would have found an example to work from.

Comment: I made some edits to the above. But I can't seem to get the events to handle correctly.

Comment: Rather than just throwing more non-working code into the mix, you may want to spend some time taking a tutorial to learn the basics. Learning those would vastly reduce the amount of time you have to deal with *brain hurts* and will be a lot less frustrating to you.

Comment: the logic doesn't make since to me. thats why I am asking for help. A big issue here is I don't understand enough to know what I am asking. I can't really even google this well as I don't know what this is called. Looking up event handing just gives me more garbage I don't understand.